# Highchart is blank

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highchart from mySQL data. The problem is that it does not return anything.

So far i've added the required libraries in my header file.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">
```

Then i've added following code in the file where i want to show the chart.

```
global $post;
    foreach ($balanceQuery as $row) 
    { 

        $value = $row->balance;
        $datetime = $row->post_date * 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
        $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
    }

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container'
      },
      series: [{
         data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
      }]
});
</script>
```

and finally i add this html code:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;"></div>
```

Why is it not showing anything?

**Another test:**

I've tried following now which actually prints out the values in a chart however i cant seem put the dates in?

**Test:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chartdiv = document.createElement("div");
chartdiv.className = "huge-container";

var seriesOptions = {
        data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
 }

var chartOptions = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'huge-container',
     },
     series: seriesOptions,
}


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);

</script>
```

Comment: Sry i forgot console error highcharts.com/errors/13

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
```

Should probably be this

```
$data = [$datetime, $value];
```

And this

```
join($data, ',')
```

Should be

```
implode(',', $data)
```

For consistency with current php specs

I am not familiar with the charting plugin you are using, but this is assuming that your `$balanceQuery` variable is defined and has query results.

Comment: Dont think that this is the error the first code is from highcharts website. i forgot to say console error: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Comment: I would post that console error in your original post.  However `$data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";` is not going to work with join/implode call.  Which might be why you are having a console error.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your chart options and series options before you istantiate the `chart`.

```
var seriesOptions = {
        data: [[<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>],
 }

var chartOptions = {
     chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
     },
     series: seriesOptions,
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

Also, notice the changes proposed by @Jacob.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined is the console result

Comment: Random i still get Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 ....

Comment: Are you calling the script before the `<div>` is created?

Comment: It is a part of a function where i provide your code in a function and then the function return the div.

Comment: @PeterPik so you're creating the `<div>` in the function?

Comment: Yes i'm creating it in the function

Comment: @PeterPik Ah I think that's your problem. You need to create the `div` in the DOM before you try to render a chart to it.

Comment: I've added code at the bottom where i DOM a div, but nothing is changed still error 13

Comment: @PeterPik you said you added it "at the bottom" which I am interpreting as AFTER you are creating the chart. You need to create the `div` BEFORE you try to render the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your php code as external file. Then inside modify this section:

```
$data[] = array($datetime, $value]);
```

and use echo json_encode($data);

```
In the end, in javascript use $.getJSON('path/to/file.php',function(data){
  //load chart
})
```

to load data and initialise chart inside